# Laravel Spark Users Field

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

Our system used Laravel Spark and it started by another developer but left the company.   I was asked to clean and remove unwanted table and fields but I think the user table has a lot of 'spark fields'.

Can you  point me to any docs where can I get the list of those 'spark fields'.

Answer (score 0):

The migrations registered by the package should be in your vendor folder, most likely in `/vendor/spark` or `/vendor/laravel/spark`. There should be a directory of migrations that the package ran, which should help you determine what database changes it made.